# Whats a good book on data analysis for someone with solid understanding of statistics?

Tags: statistics, book-recommendation, data-analysis

In about four months I will start helping out in a bee research center. For this job, anyone with a background in science or lab-work can apply and its mainly to help doing the tedious little things here and there, but because of my background in mathematics, they asked me whether I could help them with some data analysis. I have a solid understanding of probability theory and statistics, but on a purely theoretical level. So I would like to prepare myself for this task.

**What would be a good book for someone with a decent understanding of probability theory and statistics wishing to learn practical data analysis?**

Answer (score 1):

For someone with background in probability and statistics, [Applied linear statistical models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007310874X) 
 by Kutner et. al. seems really good. It covers linear regression models in detail, with all the necessary mathematical vigor and practical examples.